# When should I place a bounty on my question?

Tags: support, bounty

Just wondering if anyone has looked at the data for this site to get an Idea of when would be the best time to bounty a question. Relevance is for the goal of maximising the number of views on the given question.

What are the high traffic days?

Comment: A bounty lasts one week, which takes you through every day of the week. Do you mean what times of year are more active?

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/are-there-any-suggestions-on-how-frequently-and-how-many-times-one-should-offer?rq=1

Comment: If someone can post time series graph of the site traffic, that would help.

Comment: For other reasons I posted such a graph in [this question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4157/472).

Comment: Also, take a look at the answers to [this question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/bounties-havent-yielded-answers-what-next).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thursdays/fridays and pre chagim peak periods no? maximising views would be to post on a wednesday if next wednesday is a yomtov. Is there a difference between chanuka traffic compared to regular traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users with 25k rep have access to [site analytics](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/site-analytics).  Here is a graph from there of site traffic over the last year:

[image: from site analytics]

Those deep dips are Saturdays, as you would expect.  Throughout the rest of the week, there doesn't seem to be a lot of variation.  Besides, bounties run for a week, so even if you post one on Friday afternoon (arguably the worst time in the week to do so), there will still be plenty of time for people to see it.

The graph starts November 1 2015.  Chanukah last year began on December 6.  I see no significant Chanukah bump.  The two spikes in March are (1) the start of Purim Torah season and (2) erev Purim.  The spike in October is erev Yom Kippur.

I wondered if there might be a dip in answers around Yom Tov, e.g. because people are busy cleaning for Pesach.  I'm singling out answers since that's what a bounty tries to attract.  Here is a graph of new answers over the same time period.

[image: also from analytics]

So, not really.

**Recommendation:** Post your bounty when you want to draw attention.  It will run long enough for minor fluctuations to not matter.  However, posting right before yom tov will cost you 1-2 days of visibility, so you probably want to avoid those few times during the year.

Comment: Do you have a csv file or spreadsheet that contains the data? I want to play with it a little and see if i can find anything of interest. Thank you!